# Can not update org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa dependency within maven

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I have project with root pom.xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.cooperok</groupId>
  <artifactId>project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.war.plugin.version>3.1.0</maven.war.plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.6.2</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure-processor</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
      <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.11</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.atteo</groupId>
      <artifactId>evo-inflector</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
      <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
      <version>4.6.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.200</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

spring-boot-starter-data-jpa includes **org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa** dependency.
So I expect that version of `spring-data-jpa` will be the same as version of `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` which is depending from parent and equal 2.3.4.RELEASE.
This is according to [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.3.4.RELEASE)

But somehow version is fixed to `2.1.9.RELEASE`

`mvn dependency:tree`

```
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.1.9.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.1.9.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.1.8.RELEASE:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.8.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.1.8.RELEASE:compile
```

I can't update it anyway and use new features. I've tried to run in terminal `mvn clean install -U` or even remove ~/.m2/ folder. Version is always 2.1.9.RELEASE.

Previous version of parent was 2.1.12.RELEASE

Comment: Please post full pom file...

Comment: @khmarbaise done

Comment: Hm... I don't know why but there was <dependencyManagemen> block in pom.xml which is not neccessary

Comment: First remove the explicit given dependency for spring-data-jpa with version 2.3.1.RELEASE and second remove the dependencyManagement part which imports spring-boot-dependencies in version 2.1.6.RELEASE. That will solve your problem. The dependencies will be defined via the parent. The dependencyManagement block will only make sense if you are not inheriting from the spring boot parent. Also remove the manual given version for lombok cause spring book defines already that Take a deep look here: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.3.4.RELEASE/pom